# create a custom method get experience of the employee model by considering the year of joining as parameter

Tags: backbone.js

Create a custom method get experience of the employee model by considering the year of joining as parameter

Create Employee model with properties employee_id, name, year_of_joining and experience

Comment: Plz provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

From the question asked by Hacker Rank there are few test cases out of that one generally fails .

which says expected 22 instead of  0 .

So the complete answer is posted here.

So the Answer to the question is

var Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
//Write your code here

```
default:
{
   employee_id:1111,
   name:'Sarah Roe',
   year_of_joining:1999,
   address:'ABC Street',
   experience: null
},
getExperience: function (year_of_joining) {
  var current_date = new Date();
  var current_year = current_date.getFullYear();
  var calculated_exp = (current_year) - (year_of_joining);

  *this.set({ experience: calculated_exp });*
  return calculated_exp;
}
```

});

var employee = new Employee({ employee_id: 721, name: "Shrikrishna", year_of_joining: 1999, experience: 22});
//please add properties and values of Employee model
//employee.set({'experience': employee.get('year_of_joining')}) ;
alert("Experience of " + employee.get("name") + " is " + employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining')) + " years");

```
</script>
```